# Emulating a ROLLUP without that keyword

Tags: mysql, postgresql, group-by, rollup

In postgres, I can emulate a two dimensional pivot table by doing a query such as:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
GROUP BY
    ROLLUP(x,y,z), -- ROWS
    ROLLUP(a,b,c)  -- COLS
```

As a concrete example [in dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ad1c573acc90539c5c5c4dfddb29f776):

[image]

However, if a database did not have access to the `ROLLUP` keyword, how could this be emulated? I know a one-dimensional `ROLLUP` could be done with a `UNION ALL`, such as:

```
SELECT a, b, SUM(c) FROM Input GROUP BY ROLLUP(a, b);
-->
SELECT NULL, NULL, SUM(c) FROM Input               UNION ALL
SELECT a,    NULL, SUM(c) FROM Input GROUP BY a    UNION ALL
SELECT a,    b,    SUM(c) FROM Input GROUP BY a, b;
```

But how could this be done without access to the `ROLLUP` keyword? We an use postgres (or mysql) as the database here, but in your answer just refrain from using the `ROLLUP` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate this also with `UNION ALL`s since we have:

```
GROUP BY ROLLUP(a,b)
--> GROUP BY (), (a), (a,b)
```

So with `ROLLUP(a,b), ROLLUP(x,y)` we multiply the products together so we get:

```
GROUP BY ROLLUP(a,b), (x,y)
--> GROUP BY (), a, (a,b) *cross product* (), x, (x,y)
--> (),() + (),x + (),x,y + a,() + a,x + a,x,y + a,b,(), a,b,x, a,b,x,y
```

So applying it to the original question we would have:

```
WITH sales (Year, Half, Category, Product, Revenue) AS (
SELECT 2020,    'H1',   'Electronics',  'Phone',    200 UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,    'H1',   'Electronics',  'Computer', 300 UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,    'H2',   'Electronics',  'Phone',    100 UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,    'H2',   'Electronics',  'Computer', 175 UNION ALL
SELECT 2021,    'H1',   'Electronics',  'Phone',    109 UNION ALL
SELECT 2021,    'H1',   'Electronics',  'Computer', 32  UNION ALL
SELECT 2021,    'H2',   'Electronics',  'Phone',    93  UNION ALL
SELECT 2021,    'H2',   'Electronics',  'Computer', 111
)


SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS "sum", NULL AS category, NULL AS product, NULL AS year, NULL AS half FROM Sales GROUP BY (),() UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Revenue), NULL, NULL, Year, NULL FROM Sales GROUP BY (),Year UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Revenue), NULL, NULL, Year, Half FROM Sales GROUP BY (),Year,Half UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Revenue), Category, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM Sales GROUP BY Category,() UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Revenue), Category, NULL, Year, NULL FROM Sales GROUP BY Category,Year UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Revenue), Category, NULL, Year, Half FROM Sales GROUP BY Category,Year,half UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Revenue), Category, Product, NULL, NULL FROM Sales GROUP BY Category,Product,() UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Revenue), Category, Product, Year, NULL FROM Sales GROUP BY Category,Product,Year UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Revenue), Category, Product, Year, half FROM Sales GROUP BY Category,Product,Year,Half
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=be3b0d89ad97eaf44b522caf0df9d7da